# Android and GUI

Tags: android, user-interface

I am creating a game for my college and I have some trouble working with the GUI. I have very little experience in graphics and UI in general.

It’s a board game, so I have a **stable board** that the player can pick cards and roll dice. I create [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oMS4.jpg) with Photoshop but here comes my question. Should I import that as **an image in a layout** and *add buttons, cards and create interactive areas* with editing the .xml code? Is there another way cause I think that as a little "sloppy"?

A visual example of my question is: how is [this](https://lh5.ggpht.com/pgBmBzkdngwm2J8ABGu61zQWpyATS2qbT6VSYW4rKy-PG_erZQXQrKE8Ir--wpyzMjYd=h900-rw) created?

Thanks for your time and your answers.

Comment: have you looked in to OpenGL es 2.0 http://pragprog.com/book/kbogla/opengl-es-2-for-android

Answer (score 0):

Use a GlSurfaceView to set the background and addtional buttons ect.. http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html